# Why does Treeview in tkinter change position and column width when I load data from excel?

Tags: python, tkinter

The problem I have is that after updating a Treeview object, the width of the column changes. This is the code I have written. I am not sure why upload changes how the table looks. In particlar, it seems to me that the code for populate_treeview is identical to the way I populated it in the main function.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
import pandas as pd


class EdibleTreeviewWithUpload(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, application, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, show='headings', selectmode='browse')
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.open_button = tk.Button(self, text="Open File", command=self.open_file)
        self.open_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def open_file(self):
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[
            ("Excel files", "*.xlsx *.xlsb *.xlsm"),
            ("CSV files", "*.csv")
        ])

        if file_path:
            if file_path.lower().endswith((".xlsx", ".xlsb", ".xlsm", ".csv")):
                df = pd.read_excel(file_path) if file_path.lower().endswith(
                    (".xlsx", ".xlsm", ".xlsb")) else pd.read_csv(file_path)
                self.clear_treeview()
                self.populate_treeview(df)

    def clear_treeview(self):
        for item in self.tree.get_children():
            self.tree.delete(item)

    def populate_treeview(self, df):
        columns = df.columns.tolist()

        self.tree["columns"] = columns
        for idx, col in enumerate(columns):
            self.tree.heading(f"#{idx+1}", text=col)
            self.tree.column(f"#{idx+1}", anchor=tk.CENTER, width=100)

        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            values = [str(row[col]) for col in columns]
            self.tree.insert("", "end", values=values)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Editable TreeView Table")

    tree = EdibleTreeviewWithUpload(root)
    tree.tree['columns'] = ('Name', 'Age', 'Occupation')

    tree.tree.heading('#1', text='Name')
    tree.tree.heading('#2', text='Age')
    tree.tree.heading('#3', text='Occupation')

    tree.tree.column('#1', anchor=tk.CENTER, width=100)
    tree.tree.column('#2', anchor=tk.CENTER, width=100)
    tree.tree.column('#3', anchor=tk.CENTER, width=100)

    # Sample data
    data = [
        ("John Doe", "30", "Engineer"),
        ("Jane Smith", "25", "Teacher"),
        ("Bob Johnson", "45", "Doctor"),
    ]

    for item in data:
        tree.tree.insert('', 'end', values=item)

    tree.grid(column=1, row=1)
    root.mainloop()
```

This is how it looks like [image: Before],

comparing to how it looks [image: After].

Comment: Interestingly, if you add `tree.tree["columns"] = ('Name', 'Age', 'Occupation')` in the initialization code _after_ setting the column widths, the initialize size will larger. It is that line in your function that causes the size to change.

Comment: where did i set column width?

Comment: _"where did i set column width"_ - in this and similar statements: `tree.tree.column('#1', anchor=tk.CENTER, width=100)`.

Comment: I see what you mean now. This seems weird... in theory one should be able to do this. Maybe in the case the column changes, we should delete the existing table and create a new instance.

Comment: I solved this problem by calling self.tree.destroy() and then recreate the object.

Comment: Don't need to destroy the treeview.  Call `self.tree.grid_remove()` at the beginning of `populate_treeview()` and `self.tree.grid()` at the end of the function.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the issue you're facing is related to the width of the columns in the Treeview object changing after updating it. After reviewing your code, I couldn't find any immediate reasons why the width would change specifically when loading data from a file.

However, I noticed that the column widths are initially set to 100 in the EdibleTreeviewWithUpload class, and then later in the main function, you're setting the column widths again to 100. This duplication may lead to unexpected behavior.

To investigate the issue further, you can try the following steps:

1-Remove the column width settings in the main function: Since you're already setting the column widths in the EdibleTreeviewWithUpload class, there is no need to set them again in the main function. Remove the following lines from the main function:

```
tree.tree.column('#1', anchor=tk.CENTER, width=100)
tree.tree.column('#2', anchor=tk.CENTER, width=100)
tree.tree.column('#3', anchor=tk.CENTER, width=100)
```

2-Check if the data being loaded from the file is causing the issue: Try loading a sample dataset using the populate_treeview method directly in the open_file method, without using the external file. If the column widths remain consistent, it indicates that the issue may be related to the data being loaded from the file.

Replace the line self.populate_treeview(df) in the open_file method with the following code:

```
# Sample data
data = [
    ("John Doe", "30", "Engineer"),
    ("Jane Smith", "25", "Teacher"),
    ("Bob Johnson", "45", "Doctor"),
]
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=df.columns)
self.populate_treeview(sample_df)
```

This will populate the Treeview widget with sample data instead of the data loaded from the file.
By performing these steps, you can narrow down the possible causes of the column width changes and further investigate the issue.

Comment: Hello, thank you. If I remove the width bit, it is now the same before and after, but I do not understand in that case, how do I set the width?

Comment: For instance, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376726/how-to-change-ttk-treeview-column-width-and-weight-in-python-3-3

Comment: I don't think it's the data that's causing it. It's this statement: `self.tree["columns"] = columns`. Remove that, and the columns don't change.